# Knockout data-bind syntax in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, razor, knockout.js

In this simple CSS Knockout binding

```
<tag data-bind="css: { 'class_1': condition1, 'class_2': condition2 }" />
```

I'd like to port `class_1` and `class_2` to C# variables. This is my first attempt:

```
<tag data-bind="css: { '@class1': condition1, '@class2': condition2 }" />
```

Other attempts resulted in me having to declare a separate variable containing the binding statement.

```
string bind = string.Format("'{0}': condition1, '{1}': condition2", class1, class2)
<tag data-bind = "css: { @bind }" />
```

and, finally:

```
string bind = string.Format("css: {{ '{0}': condition1, '{1}': condition2 }}", class1, class2)
<tag data-bind = "@bind" />
```

None of these blocked the rendering of the page but the first two results in Visual Studio indicating a syntax error.
I'd like to do this bind:

- Without the need to istanciate a separate variable
- Without any syntax error popping out in Visual Studio 2012 (and
  screwing up code collapsing)

Is it possible?

The last example, the only one which doesn't give syntax errors, sacrifies code readability, especially for larger statements. Is there any alternative which looks more like my first attempt? Knockout MVC seems a little bit too invasive: is there something similar but which can solve *only* this issue?

Comment: Are you planning on updating the CSS classes using Knockout or will it be static?

Comment: static. The name of the classes will be static from the client perspective. I'd like razor to print those names and he's doing it but not without screwing up the ide environment.

Comment: now that you asked me... I could assign the class name to a js variable with razor and then use knockout only. Could be a solution...

Comment: I was thinking that as well or you could alter your KO VM to take the classes via the constructor and assign them to properties.

Comment: that could be a good solution! Can KO take js variables as classes names in the bind statement?

Answer (score 2):

I've not got VS 2012 installed on my machine any more, but VS 2013's syntax highlighting accepts this code:

```
<style>
    .myClass {
        color: red;
    }
</style>

@{
    var MyClass = "myClass";
}

<div id="fooId">
    <span data-bind="css: { '@MyClass': enableClass }, text: myText"></span>
</div>

@section scripts{    
    <script>
        var vm = {
            enableClass: ko.observable(true),
            myText: ko.observable('foobarbaz')
        };
        ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById('fooId'));
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
class1 = @Model.CssClass1;
class2 = @Model.CssClass2;

var viewModel = function(class1, class2) {
    self = this;

    self.classOne= ko.observable(class1);
    self.classOne= ko.observable(class2);

    self.condition_1 = // something
    self.condition_2 = // something
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel (class1, class2));
```

Then just apply the bindings as you showed in your first example:

```
<tag data-bind="css: { classOne : condition1, classTwo: condition2 }" />
```

Comment: I was wondering: are you sure he won't interpret classOne literally? I mean, by applying the class "classOne" or "classTwo" to the tag? I need a few minutes to set it this up: we'll know soon.

Comment: for example, visual studio is not accepting $root.something as the class name

Comment: can you post your KO view model and html in the question

Comment: I've made a fiddle. $root is used because in my code I need to do this thing inside of a loop. http://jsfiddle.net/gjjAC/3/

Comment: as a general rule, it looks like he can't reference class names as variables. http://jsfiddle.net/gjjAC/5/

Comment: the only way to do it would be writing a method that returns the class name but this defies the sense of having data and view separation. http://jsfiddle.net/gjjAC/7/

Answer (score -1):

@Saturnix, since you said that the class value is only variable from the server, you can--and probably should--keep the class variables out of your KO model. Here's what I'm thinking:

```
@{ 
var class1 = Model.condition1 ? 'class1' : '';
var class2 = Model.condition2 ? 'class2' : '';
}
<input data-bind="value: myValue" class="@class1 @class2" />
```

Or, you could simplify your view by modifying the view model to contain class variables directly. Such as:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public bool Condition1 {get; set;}
    public bool Condition2 {get; set;}
    public string Class1 
    {
        get { return Condition1 ? 'class1' : ''; }
    }
    public string Class2
    {
        get { return Condition2 ? 'class2' : ''; }
    }
}

<input data-bind="value: myValue" class="@Model.Class1 @Model.Class2" />
```

Or even:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public bool Condition1 {get; set;}
    public bool Condition2 {get; set;}
    public string classes 
    {
        get 
        { 
            var classes = new List<string>();
            if (Condition1) classes.Add("class1");
            if (Condition2) classes.Add("class2");
            return string.Join(",", classes);
        }
    }
    public string Class2
    {
        get { return Condition2 ? 'class2' : ''; }
    }
}
<input data-bind="value: myValue" class="@Model.classes" />
```

Comment: He wants the application of the class to be dynamic, meaning depending on which condition is being met a different class is applied. That is why he is binding, the way you are proposing is a "set it and forget it" solution.

Comment: Yeah. My mistake. I thought I read that the style application were determined server side but I see now that it's the name of the classes which are static.